# Protect attributes to be updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've got a RPG website and I want users to be able to set their name on registering but not when they're editing their profile. But I want as an admin to be able to edit it.

Since I use update_attributes in the update action, I think they're able to update their first_name not using the classic form I provide.

Is there a way to do this with ActiveRecord validations or simply in the controller ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `attr_accessible :name, :as => :admin` to your `User` model, and in the sign-up controller use `@user.update_attributes(params[:user], :as => :admin)`. The `update` action should instead use `@user.update_attributes(params[:user])` without the `:as => :admin` option.

More on this topic: [Rails 3.1 Overview](http://railscasts.com/episodes/265-rails-3-1-overview)

Comment: That's great ! You think I can use a `:as => :signup` and a `:as => :admin` on different actions ? And user attr_accessible as :signup and :admin ?

Answer (score 0):

This is easier to do through the controller, because the controller is where you have access to the logged-in user.  So, in your controller:

```
# When the form is submitted
unless @current_user.is_an_admin?
  # List of attributes to allow non-admins to change
  allowed_fields = %w[allowed_field_1 allowed_field_2]
  # Remove any non-allowed fields from the params
  params[:user].delete_if {|key, value| !allowed_fields.include?(key.to_s)}
end
@user.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

You *could* do it through the User model, but you'd have to have some way to pass the editing user's status to the model and then add a bunch of conditional validations.

Comment: Disagree! Controllers should be clean, and this is definitely a task for the model.

Comment: Eh....IMHO, passing this off to the model breaks MVC.  The current user and their admin status are essentially dependent on the session variable, and the session is inherently part of the controller, not the model.  The model methods should *never* depend on the state of another model unless those two models are directly associated.